# c++ if specific words from string

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, cin

I'd like to check in an if statement for several words from a defined string (cin), so that it accepts different using of capital and small initial letters .

```c++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string BothMods;

cout << "Are both online?" << endl;
cin >> BothMods;

if (BothMods == "Yes", "YES", "yes"{
    cout <<"Both are online" << endl;
```

...

But when I type in one of the three conditions, the condition is always false (else gets executed). If I only use one (like if (BothMods == "Yes") ) it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check each case individually using the OR operator if you want to check more than one case.

```
if (BothMods == "Yes" || BothMods == "YES" || BothMods == "yes") {
    // do whatever
}
```

Comment: If it worked, don't forget to mark this as the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @VictorTran For that OP would have to wait for the 15min cool down :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 Oh, of course... I forgot about that :)

Comment: I would recommend to convert `BothMods` into lower case (or upper case) an make the check against `"yes"` (or `"YES"`).